# Error in creating threads. warning: passing argument 3 of ‘pthread_create’ from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am having trouble creating a pool of threads. I continuously get the warning:

```
warning: passing argument 3 of ‘pthread_create’ from incompatible pointer type
```

I have searched for questions but none of them has solved the problem for me.
Here is the code I am using for creating the threads

```
for(j=2;j<THREADNUMBER+2;j++){
    id[j] = j;
    if(pthread_create(&thread_array[j],NULL,requestHandler,(void*)id[j])!=0){
        perror("Error creating thread ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the function signature for `requestHandler()`.

Comment: I think this is the important part
void *requestHandler(void* n)

Comment: Hmmm.. maybe the parser mangled your comment.  Please use backquotes around code segments.  Is the signature `void requestHandler(void n)` or `void *requestHandler(void *n)`?

Comment: it was 'void *requesHandler(void *n)'

Comment: The "incompatible pointer type" warning means whatever you gave it was not of the type `void *(*)(void *)`.

Comment: Is that the *only* warning you're getting? What if you use `-Wall`?

Comment: It was not the only warning but in this lines yes it was

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [man pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html):

> ```
> #include <pthread.h>
>
> int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
>                       void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
> ```
>
> Compile and link with -pthread.

The third argument is a pointer to a function that returns a `void *` and takes *one argument* of type `void *`.  By using just a generic pointer value of type `void *` (i.e. a memory address) as the argument and return type, it is a function that can (at least indirectly) accept anything as an argument, and return the address of anything as a result.  This makes it a rather general function, but still has a fixed function signature.

Your function `requestHandler()` does not seem to match this signature.  Make sure that your `requestHandler()` accepts exactly one argument of type `void *` and returns a `void *`.  It should look something like:

```
void *requestHandler(void *arg) {
    ...
}
```